# Excel not passing @Parameter from cell value to SQL Query

Tags: excel, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to use a parameter from a cell (NOT using VBA).

As i saw in many answers, i put the **?** inside the connection (In Excel, Data -> Connections) and it made the "Parameters" button available, and created @Parâmetro1 (not English Excel) parameter, which i associated with a cell value (Get Value from Cell: **=VendasMensais!$J$1**).

[image: Before Updating With @Parameter on Query]

I changed the Query to DECLARE the @Parâmetro1 (if i don't, I get the '*must declare scalar...*' error):

```
DECLARE @Parâmetro1 int;
```

But when i click to update all connections, with the cell containing an year, the @Parâmetro1 never works. Returns no results:

[image: Query]

[image: Empty Results]

```
--I guess it is sending:
AND T3.Ano IN ()
```

But if i manually change back to:

```
AND T3.Ano IN (2018)
```

I get the results i want.

My question is, why isn't the @Parâmetro1 being sent from the cell value, that is correctly set on the "Parameters" section, and correctly filled with an year?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3rd party Oracle ODBC drivers (like from Actual Tech or others), try updating to the latest driver version. I had the exact same issue and just solved it by updating the ODBC drivers.